# Fetching multiple looped textboxes' values

Tags: php, html, arrays

So I have this program where the user sets up a database table. First, I ask them how many fields they want.

**first.php**

```
<html>
<form name="formCreateFields" method="post" align="center" action="second.php">
    <p>Number of fields: &nbsp; <input type ="text" name="fieldsNum"/> &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="submitFieldsNum" value=" Submit "/></p><br>
</form>
</html>
```

Then I loop the fields, depending on their input above.

**second.php**

```
<?php

echo "<form name='formSetupFields' method='post' align='center' action='third.php'>";

for ($z=1; $z<=$_POST['fieldsNum']; $z++) {
    echo "<table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan=2> <big> $z </big> &nbsp; &nbsp;</th>   <th>Name</th>   <th>Type</th>   <th>Length</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='fieldName$z'></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='fieldType$z'></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='fieldLength$z'></td>
        </tr>
        </table><br><br>";
}

<input type='submit' name='submitFieldSetup'>
</form>";
?>
```

I'm having problems after this. I've been trying to test fetching them by putting them in an array and using `foreach` to view them but can't seem to get anywhere. I thought it was okay to use something like `$_POST['fieldName$z']` but I guess I was wrong.

I just need to find out how I could fetch all the inputs in the second file. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fieldsNum` is a number, the `for` should be fine in this case, just properly concatenate the values:

```
echo "<form name='formSetupFields' method='post' align='center' action='third.php'>";
    echo "<table align='center'>";
        echo '
        <tr>
            <th rowspan=2></th>   <th>Name</th>   <th>Type</th>   <th>Length</th>
        </tr>';
        for ($z = 1; $z <= $_POST['fieldsNum']; $z++) {
            echo "
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' name='inputs[$z][name]'></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='inputs[$z][type]'></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='inputs[$z][length]'></td>
                </tr>
                ";

        }
    echo '</table><br><br>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submitFieldSetup'>";
echo '</form>';
```

Then in `third.php`;

```
if(isset($_POST['inputs'])) {
    $inputs = $_POST['inputs'];
    foreach($inputs as $input) {
        echo $input['name'];
        echo $input['type'];
        echo $input['length'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the proper concatenation. But how would I fetch the inputs after this?

Comment: @Suika then, just like a form submission, `action="third.php"`, most likely the input will go there

Comment: yes, but I was hoping to get help for the foreach loop to display all the inputs. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @Suika oh okay, check my revision, should give you the basic idea

Comment: Ah, I see. Exactly what I was looking for. Sorry if my question wasn't that clear the first time. Thank you so much for the help! :D